# Can Windows Server 2008 R2 be set to auto logon at boot up?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, automation

I would like to have it so that if the system is rebooted, it auto logs back in to a particular user name so that certain applications can be run under that username. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this works on Windows Server 2008 but here is technet kb article with instructions how to do it for windows 2003.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737/en-us

Remember, this is a serious security risk to I dont recommend you do this in the first place. 
If you must do this, the screen saver to 1 minute and enable "on resume, password protect"